# Booleans in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I am a beginner and started to learn the java language. I encountered a problem in the book about booleans. I don't know how to find the value of the questions and I was wondering if someone can give me a sample of how the code is supposed to look like. Help would really be appreciated.

Question in the book:

Suppose the value of b is false and the value of x is 0. What is the value of each of the following expressions

**a)** `b && x == 0`

**b)** `b || x == 0`

**c)** `!b && x == 0`

**d)** `!b || x == 0`

**e)** `b && x != 0`

**f)** `b || x != 0`

**g)** `!b && x != 0`

**h)** `!b || x != 0`

I just don't know how I would execute this problem, help!
Thanks

Comment: Understand meaning of Logical operator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Look up [truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table), `&&` is `conjuction`, `||` is `disjunction`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is not a boolean/int comparation. Right side operations are logical int/int evaluations, which return a boolean (x == 0 can be true or false)

Comment: @CristianMeneses my bad. Then, OP please grab a pencil and a piece of paper and do the exercise, otherwise you won't learn.

Comment: parenthesize stuff based on precedence it'll help you understand.

Comment: The important things to understand:  1) In Java `boolean` is not a numeric type and cannot be used in expressions with `int`.  2) `&&` and `||` are "short-circuiting" operators, so if the result can be determined by evaluating the left-hand side, the right-hand side is not even evaluated (and, in fact, MUST NOT be evaluated).  3) Operator precedence -- find a table online and bookmark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you approach this problem:

- Recall that `&&` and `||` need `boolean` on both sides
- Recall that `!` inverts the value of a `boolean`
- Recall that binary operations `!=` and `==` convert pairs of `int`s to `boolean`s
- Start with the right side; decide if it's `true` or `false`
- Put the result from the line above in the expression
- Compute the result using the truth table for the corresponding logical operator.

Let's use your first couple of exercises as examples:

`b && x == 0`

You know that `b` is `false`, so the result of `AND` is known right away: it's `false` - there's no need to do anything else.

`b || x == 0`

1. You know that `b` is `false`, so the result of `OR` is not known right away.
2. Compute `x == 0` (the value is `true`)
3. Compute `b || true` (the value is `true`, because `OR`-ing with `true` is always `true`).

Comment: The order of computation is wrong: [15.24. Conditional-Or Operator ||](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) _At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first. If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated. If the value of the left-hand operand is false, then the right-hand expression is evaluated;_ Whichs means: 1. Compute `b` 2. `b` is `false`, so compute `x==0`. 3. Evaluate hole expression to `true`.

Comment: @MichaelKonietzka I said nothing about the order of computation: OP does not need to do what compiler does to obtain the result of the logical expressions in question. I did it on purpose, to avoid mixing the "pure logic" and its implementation.

Comment: Of course he need to do what the compiler does, because these are Java expressions, not just boolean algebra.

Comment: @MichaelKonietzka I disagree: considering the assignment's lack of context and simplicity of the expressions involved, it appears that whoever created the assignment wants to teach OP some boolean algebra first, before proceeding to order of evaluation. The fact that the Java syntax is used for these expressions is secondary to understanding their meaning.

Comment: I disagree: _left-hand operand first_ and _short-circuit_ are the key-features of `&&` and `||`. To teach just boolean algebra, just use `&` and `|`. Regarding `b || x == 0`, the computation of `x==0` at first is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java, `!=` and `==`  have **higher** precedence over `&&` and `||` (logical AND and OR). So

```
b && x == 0
```

is nothing but

```
b && (x == 0) // --> here x==0 gets evaluated first due to precedence
```

which is

```
b && true // (cause x is 0)
```

and since `b` is `false` final result is `false`

Comment: No. `b` is false so there is no evaluation of `x==0` on the right side of `&&`. `false && x==0` can never be true, so short-circuit evaluation is done, which means no evaluation of `x==0`.

Comment: I have removed the sidenote, I think @MichaelKonietzka is correct, its due to short circuit

Comment: But you still say `(x == 0)` gets evaluated first.  That is not true.

Comment: So, making a distinction between precedence order and evaluation order?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to find the value of an expression is to print the expression to screen, in your case:

```
boolean b = false;
int x = 0;

System.out.println(b && x == 0);   // false
System.out.println(b || x == 0);   // true
System.out.println(!b && x == 0);  // true
System.out.println(!b || x == 0);  // true
System.out.println(b && x != 0);   // false
System.out.println(b || x != 0);   // false
System.out.println(!b && x != 0);  // false
System.out.println(!b || x != 0);  // true
```

You must put this in a Java class and run it, for example like this:

```
public class HelloBoolean {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        // code comes here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Conditional Operators
>
> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. 
>   These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only 
>   if needed.
>
> && Conditional-AND
>
> || Conditional-OR

from [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> a) b && x == 0

`&&` is conditional-and which means, the right operand is only evaluated if the left operand is `true`.
In your case b is false, which means, evaluation ends, because `false && <anything>` can never be true regardless of `<anything>.`

> b) b || x == 0

`||` is conditional-or, which means the right operand is only evaluated, if the first operand is `false`.
In your case b is false, so we need to evaluate `x==0` to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The book should explain what each of the operations does. You can test the result by simply:

```
boolean b = false;
int x = 0;
System.out.println(b && (x == 0));
```

The output should give you the answer true or false.

Answer (score 0):

When `b` is the expression on the left-side: anything with `&&` will return `false` since `b` is false.

When the leftside contains `b` - every `||` will return `true` only if the expression on the right side returns `true` (otherwise it'll return false).

Let's go over a few of the examples you posted:

a) `b && x == 0`  => will evaluate to `false` since `b` is false and we use `&&` (AND)

b) `b || x == 0`  => will evaluate to `true`  since `x==0` is true and we use `||` (OR)

If the left side contains `!b` then any expression that has `&&` will evaluate to `true` only if the right side evaluates to `true`. And if the expression has `||` it will 
evaluates to `true` regardless of the expression on the right-side.

c) `!b && x == 0` => will evaluate to `true`: since both sides evaluate to `true`

d) `!b || x == 0` => will evaluate to `true`: since both sides evaluate to `true`

g) `!b && x != 0` => will evaluate to `false` because `&&` requires both sides to be true but the rightside evaluates to `false`

h) `!b || x != 0` => will evaluate to `true` because the leftside evaluates to `true` and we use OR (`||`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to learn Java, fire up eclipse and do the following:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    boolean b = false;
    int x = 0;
    if(b || x == 0) System.out.println(true);
    else System.out.println(false);
}
```

Then you have your answer (to the first one at least).

Answer (score 0):

First of all "0" is not "false" in java (unlike many other languages). It is pure int.

Assuming you are familiar with the main function. 
Remember to save the file with the same name as its public class.

In this case BooleansDemo.java

*The precedence rules are well described in answers prior to this.*

```
public class BooleansDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean b = false;
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println(b || x == 0);

        System.out.println(!b && x == 0);

        System.out.println(!b || x == 0);

        System.out.println(b && x != 0);

        System.out.println(b || x != 0);

        System.out.println(!b && x != 0);

        System.out.println(!b || x != 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand the operators involved.
We're dealing with five operators.

1. `&&` [Logical Conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_and): *results in `true` if **both** of its operands are true.*
   This can be given by the following truth table.

   ```
   |   A   |   B   | A && B | 
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | true  | true  |  true  |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | true  | false |  false |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | false | true  |  false |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | false | false |  false |
   ```
2. `||` [Logical Disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction): *produces a result of `true` whenever **one or more** of its operands are true.*
   This can be given by the following truth table.

   ```
   |   A   |   B   | A || B | 
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | true  | true  |  true  |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | true  | false |  true  |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | false | true  |  true  |
   +-------+-------+--------+
   | false | false |  false |
   ```
3. `!` [Negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_negation): *produces a value of `true` when its operand is false and a value of `false` when its operand is true.*
   This can be given by the following truth table.

   ```
   |   A   |  !A   |
   +-------+-------+
   | true  | false |
   +-------+-------+
   | false | true  |
   ```
4. `==` *Equal to*: For the purposes of this question, it compares two numbers, and returns `true` if both numbers are the same.
5. `!=` *Not equal to*: it's a shorthand for `!(A == B)`, *ie*, it returns `true` if the numbers are **not** the same.

Note that both `&&` and `||` benefit from [Short-circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (also known as *Shortcut Evaluation*). This means that the second operand (the right-side operand) **will only be evaluated if necessary**.

A conjunction, `&&`, requires both operands to be true. It starts by evaluating the first operand. If the first operand evaluates to `false`, the whole conjunction is false, and there's no point in evaluating the second operand.

A disjunction, `||`, requires one operand to be true. It starts by evaluating the first operand. If the first operand evaluates to `true`, the whole disjunction is true, and there's no point in evaluating the second operand.

Also note that the three remaining operands have higher priorities than `&&` and `||`. For instance, `b && x == 0` is exactly the same as `b && (x == 0)`. However, the order of evaluation still remains.

Summing up:

```
a) b && x == 0  // false: b is false, short-circuit applies

b) b || x == 0 // true: b is false, x == 0 is evaluated to true

c) !b && x == 0 // true: !b is true, and x == 0 is also true

d) !b || x == 0 // true: !b is true, short-circuit applies

e) b && x != 0 // false: b is false, short-circuit applies

f) b || x != 0 // false: b is false, x != 0 is also false

g) !b && x != 0 // false: !b is true, however x != 0 is false

h) !b || x != 0 // true: !b is true, short-circuit applies
```